# Getting error in PL/SQL program which alerts "missing or invalid option"

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_OPE AS 
  FILE_PATH         VARCHAR2(150) := 'd:\OPENTOW_'||trunc(sysdate)||'.csv';                       
  QUERY_STRING      VARCHAR2(100) := 'SPOOL'||FILE_PATH;
  STATUS            VARCHAR2(50)  := 'Withdrawn';
  DATEFORMAT        VARCHAR2(50)  := 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
  TIMEFORMAT        VARCHAR2(50)  := 'hh24:mi:ss';
  YES_FLAG          VARCHAR(3)    := 'Yes';
  NO_FLAG           VARCHAR(3)    := 'No';
  BLANK_SPACE       VARCHAR2(1)   := ' ';
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'SET ECHO OFF';
  execute immediate 'SET FEEDBACK OFF';
  execute immediate QUERY_STRING;
```

I am getting this error

> Error Message:`
>                 ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
>                 ORA-06512: at "WS", line 12
>                 ORA-06512: at line 2
>                  Process exited.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The error message refers to "WS" but that doesn't appear anywhere in your code.  `set echo off` and `set feedback off` are `SQL*Plus` commands, not SQL statements so you can't use them in a stored procedure.  `spool` is also a `SQL*Plus` command, not a SQL statement, so you can't `spool` from a stored procedure.  If your intention is to create a stored procedure that writes to a file on the database server, you could use the `utl_file` package.

Answer (score 1):

SPOOL, SET ECHO OFF, SET FEEDBACK OFF - they are all **SQL-Plus** commands, not **SQL** commands.

If you try to run any of them using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, you will get this error, for example:

```
BEGIN
 execute immediate 'SET ECHO OFF';
END;
/
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN
 execute immediate 'SET ECHO OFF';
END;
Error report -
ORA-00922: brakująca lub niepoprawna opcja
ORA-06512: przy linia 2
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
```

Sql-Plus is a client utility.
SQL is a structured query language
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE accepts **ony SQL commands**, you cannot run SQL-Plus in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, they are ony available in SQL-PLus, or (some of them) is SQL-Developer, but not in other clients like JDBC, ODBC.